# LWJGL Fullscreen while keeping aspect ratio?

Tags: fullscreen, lwjgl, aspect-ratio, fbo, render-to-texture

I want to have a fullscreen mode that keeps the aspect ratio by adding black bars on either side. I tried just creating a display mode, but I can't make it fullscreen unless it's a pre-approved resolution, and when I use a bigger diaplay than the native resolution the pixels become messed up, and lines appeared between all of the tiles in the game for some reason.

I think I need to use FBOs to render the scenario to a texture instead of the window, and then just use a fullscreen approved resolution and render the texture properly stretched out in the center of the screen, but I just don't understand how to render to a texture in order to do that, or how to stretch an image. Could someone please help me?

**EDIT**

I got fullscreen working, but it makes everything all broken looking There are random lines on the edges of anything that's written to the window. There are no glitchy lines when it's in native resolution though. Here's my code:

```
    Display.setTitle("Mega Man");

    try{
        Display.setDisplayMode(Display.getDesktopDisplayMode());
        Display.create();
    }catch(LWJGLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,1,-1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);
    glHint(GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST);
    glHint(GL_LINE_SMOOTH_HINT, GL_NICEST);

    try{Display.setFullscreen(true);}catch(Exception e){}

    int sh=Display.getHeight();
    int sw=WIDTH*sh/HEIGHT;
    GL11.glViewport(Display.getWidth()/2-sw/2, 0, sw, sh);
```

Screenshot of the glitchy fullscreen here: http://sta.sh/021fohgnmxwa

**EDIT**

Here is the texture rendering code that I use to draw everything:

```
public static void DrawQuadTex(Texture tex, int x, int y, float width, float height, float texWidth, float texHeight, float subx, float suby, float subd, String mirror){

    if (tex==null){return;}
    if (mirror==null){mirror = "";}

    //subx, suby, and subd are to grab sprites from a sprite sheet. subd is the measure of both the width and length of the sprite, as only images with dimensions that are the same and are powers of 2 are properly displayed.

    int xinner = 0;
    int xouter = (int) width;
    int yinner = 0;
    int youter = (int) height;

    if (mirror.indexOf("h")>-1){
        xinner = xouter;
        xouter = 0;
    }

    if (mirror.indexOf("v")>-1){
        yinner = youter;
        youter = 0;
    }

    tex.bind();
    glTranslatef(x,y,0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2f(subx/texWidth,suby/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xinner,yinner);
    glTexCoord2f((subx+subd)/texWidth,suby/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xouter,yinner);
    glTexCoord2f((subx+subd)/texWidth,(suby+subd)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xouter,youter);
    glTexCoord2f(subx/texWidth,(suby+subd)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xinner,youter);

    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Comment: Isn't this a problem that could be fixed with the use of glViewport? By setting up the viewport correct you should be able to keep the aspect ratio the way you want.

Comment: @PTosk Thank you! Although I'm getting another issue. I keep seeing lines between all of my objects, and everything looks off. I uploaded my code to set up the fullscreen as an edit to my question.

Comment: The link to the screenshot isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Just to keep it clean I give you a real answer and not just a comment.

The aspect ratio problem can be solved with help of glViewport. Using this method you can decide which area of the surface that will be rendered to. The default viewport will cover the whole surface.

Since the second problem with the corrupt rendering (also described here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28846531/sprite-game-in-full-screen-aliasing-issue) appeared after changing viewport I will give my thought about it in this answer as well.

Without knowing exactly how the rendering code for the tile background looks. I would guess that the problem is due to any differences in the resolution between the glViewport and glOrtho calls.
Example: If the glOrtho resolution is half the viewport resolution then each openGL unit is actually 2 pixels. If you then renders a tile between x=0 and x=9 and then the next one between x=10 and x=19 you will get an empty space between them.

To solve this you can change the resolution so that they are the same. Or you can render the tile to overlap, first one x=0 to x=10 second one x=10 to x=20 and so on.

Without seeing the tile rendering code I can't verify it this is the problem though.

Comment: Not a big fan of using int for coordinates since OpenGL uses float,but it shouldn't create this kind of problem. Can't see any problem in the code. It could be a texture atlas bleeding problem, have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894802/opengl-texture-atlas-bleeding.

Comment: I'm not sure if it's a texture atlas bleeding problem. The pixels in the fullscreen are blurred also, and I don't think texture atlas bleeding would cause that. Here, try this link to the screenshot: http://entity1037.deviantart.com/art/Glitchy-Fullscreen-Screenshot-517888561?ga_submit_new=10%253A1425611924&ga_type=edit&ga_changes=1&ga_recent=1

Comment: From a debug purpose it would be interesting to see what the result is if you disable texturing. By doing so you can see if it's a texture problem or a geometry problem. You might have to use glColor to set the target color that will be used but I think white is the default color. If you still see the lines without the texture then it's a geometry problem. In that case I would try to increase the width and height with 1 without altering the x and y values and see if that has any affect.

Comment: I replaced all of the textures with blue squares the same size as the textures, and there are no lines. The more I look at it, the more it seems like a resolution issue, even though you said the code looks fine (I don't think texture atlas bleeding causes pixels to display imperfectly and blurr together). Is there a method call that I can use to find the resolution, or some other way to check that? Or could something else be wrong?

Comment: What I meant with changing resolution was to use glOrtho(0,sw,sh,0 ,1,-1) instead of glOrtho(0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,1,-1). This gives the drawing area a 1-1 ratio between pixels and OpenGL units. This will however change the scale of everything. And when you compensate for this by multiplying each coordinate with some factor you probably ends up with the same result again.

Comment: Unless you already fixed the problem I would paint a frame in the tile texture so that the pixels next to the sky tile is in some color that is easy to spot (pink is a good one). If the lines in the output remains black and you don't see any pink then you can rule out any texture atlas bleeding issue.

Comment: I put pink around all of the sprites and changed the sprite locations, and all of the glitchy lines turned pink!! So, how the heck do I fix this issue? And is it texture atlas bleeding that's also causing the pixels to blur together instead of seamlessly resize?

Comment: I found a solution to my problem! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29219051/opengl-fullscreen-resolution-error/29219364?noredirect=1#comment46657285_29219364.    Also, thank you for your help!!