# Opengl Fullscreen Resolution Error

Tags: opengl, fullscreen, resolution

I have this fullscreen problem where the pixels in the textures blur together. The issue is NOT with drawing the images, but rather the scaling of the textures themselves, sense I can see adjacent textures in my texture sheets blur into eachother resulting in parts of textures in other textures and artifacts everywhere. I have no idea why this is happening, sense, from looking at my code, there are no apparent resolution differences.

Could someone please help me? I've been stuck on this problem for quite a while.

Code that sets up fullscreen:

```
public static final int WIDTH=256, HEIGHT=240;
public static int viewWidth, viewHeight, viewX, viewY;

public static void BeginSession(){

    Display.setTitle("Mega Man");

    try{
        Display.setDisplayMode(Display.getDisplayMode());
        Display.create();
    }catch(LWJGLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    viewHeight=Display.getHeight();
    viewWidth=WIDTH*viewHeight/HEIGHT;

    Display.setVSyncEnabled(true);

    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0,WIDTH,HEIGHT,0,1,-1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);


    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glEnable(GL11.GL_LINE_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL11.GL_LINE_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);

    glEnable(GL11.GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
    glHint(GL11.GL_POINT_SMOOTH, GL_NICEST);


    try{Display.setFullscreen(true);}catch(Exception e){}

    viewX=Display.getWidth()/2-viewWidth/2;
    viewY=Display.getHeight()/2-viewHeight/2;

    glViewport(viewX, viewY, viewWidth, viewHeight);
    //glViewport(viewX,viewY,WIDTH,HEIGHT);

    System.out.println("View Width: "+viewWidth+"\nView Height: "+viewHeight);

    textSpriteSheet = QuickLoad("Mega_Man_Font_8x8");
    highlightedTextSpriteSheet = QuickLoad("Mega_Man_Font_8x8_Yellow");
}
```

Here's the code that renders images to the screen.

```
public static void DrawQuadTex(Texture tex, int x, int y, float width, float height, float texWidth, float texHeight, float subx, float suby, float subd, String mirror){

    if (tex==null){return;}
    if (mirror==null){mirror = "";}

    //subx, suby, and subd are to grab sprites from a sprite sheet. subd is the measure of both the width and length of the sprite, as only images with dimensions that are the same and are powers of 2 are properly displayed.

    int xinner = 0;
    int xouter = (int) width;
    int yinner = 0;
    int youter = (int) height;

    if (mirror.indexOf("h")>-1){
        xinner = xouter;
        xouter = 0;
    }

    if (mirror.indexOf("v")>-1){
        yinner = youter;
        youter = 0;
    }

    tex.bind();
    glTranslatef(x,y,0);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);

    //top left
    glTexCoord2f((subx)/texWidth,(suby)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xinner,yinner);
    //top right
    glTexCoord2f((subx+subd)/texWidth,(suby)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xouter,yinner);
    //bottom right
    glTexCoord2f((subx+subd)/texWidth,(suby+subd)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xouter,youter);
    //bottom left
    glTexCoord2f((subx)/texWidth,(suby+subd)/texHeight);
    glVertex2f(xinner,youter);

    glEnd();

    glLoadIdentity();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Your problem has to do with sampling texels at the wrong position.

You want to sample at the center of each texel to avoid interpolation, but that does not happen if you naively use the range [**0.0**, **1.0**]. This is because **0.0** is on the edge of your image, it is equally close to the center of the first texel as it is the center of the last texel on the other side of the texture (when using the default `GL_REPEAT` wrap mode).

#### The following diagram illustrates this problem on a 1D texture:

http://i.msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC83860.gif

You actually need to divide your coordinates into the range: [**1.0 / (2.0 * N)**, **1.0 - 1.0 / (2.0 * N)**]

#### This should be achievable if you re-write your coordinates this way:

```
(subx + 0.5)/texWidth, (suby + 0.5)/texHeight
```

Baiscally you just need a half-texel shift, and then your problem will go away.

Comment: subx and suby are pixel coordinates in the texture, not texel coordinates. I honestly am still learning programming, and have no idea what a texel is. And when I added 0.5 like you showed above, it just shifted what part of the glitchy texture was being displayed.

Comment: @AlexanderZung: Texel is the name of each pixel in a texture. Just like fragment is what you call a pixel before it's blended into the framebuffer. What you're using here are called normalized texture coordinates, they exist in the range [0.0, 1.0]. You compute them by dividing your absolute texel position by the width or height of the texture. But like I pointed out, you want these coordinates to reference the exact center of a texel or you get interpolation between the neighboring texels.

Comment: @AlexanderZung: However, you have mentioned that you are using sprite sheets, and those have their whole host of own problems. Try setting the texture filter to `GL_NEAREST` for both MIN and MAG and see if that changes anything. Also, did you only apply `+ 0.5` to the line I mentioned? It needs to be added to every texture coordinate (so `subx+subd+0.5` as well), otherwise you will kind of just shift the problem to the other side of the quad ;)

Comment: @andon-m-coleman I changed the texture filter to nearest for min and mag, and MOST OF MY PROBLEMS WERE GONE! Well, I see a very small amount of the same problem, for instance a single flickering pink line in the middle of the screen, and an extra pixel at the bottom of the period sprite, but other than that it's looking good! Now, I WOULD actually like to fix the real issue itself, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that. And also, yes I added 0.5 to all of the texture coordinates.

Comment: @AlexanderZung: In order for me to better understand your problem, could you link to some screenshots that show the problem before you did any of the things I suggested, and after? Right now I'm sort of playing a game of intuitive guess and check and a screenshot would really help :P

Comment: @andon-m-coleman Before: https://fbcdn-sphotos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xfp1/t31.0-8/11009859_1584837751803117_3712522534440915520_o.jpg After adding 0.5: https://scontent-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xat1/t31.0-8/11058442_1584837718469787_2091926583107791332_o.jpg After GL_NEAREST filtering: https://scontent-dfw.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xft1/t31.0-8/10511639_1584886231798269_1691637919409342959_o.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderZung: Ah, I think I get what you're doing now. Actually, what you would need to do is *add* **0.5** to the coordinates that are simply `subx` and `suby` and *subtract* **0.5** from the coordinates that are `subx+subd` and `suby+subd` (before dividing by width or height of course). That _should_ produce identical results to `GL_NEAREST` filtering if I understand what is going on here.

Comment: @andon-m-coleman that doesn't work either. It gets rid of the artifacts, but it cuts of the outer edges of the textures, and the pixels are all still blurred together. Its suppose to look exactly like the GL_NEAREST filtering. https://fbcdn-sphotos-d-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t31.0-8/p720x720/10830685_1584890361797856_4958570732737031280_o.jpg

Comment: @AlexanderZung: Okay, so we've established you don't want texture interpolation at all. Then `GL_NEAREST` together with the corrected texture coordinates should be your final solution, unless I'm missing something?

Comment: @andon-m-coleman When I do GL_NEAREST with adding/subtracting 0.5 from coordinates, the small amount of artifacts go away, but half of the pixels around the edges of the sprites get cut off. HOWEVER, it seems that I can literally add/subtract 0.01 instead of 0.5 and it gets rid of the artifacts and keeps the edges of the sprites visibly the same!!!!!!! So, I don't know how to actually fix the problem, but it seems I have a good work around for it! Thank you for all of your help!